# Elements inside main div exceed width

Tags: html, css, width

I have the children elements `width` set to `100%`, but the `width`s exceed the `width` of the parent `div`.

**Code:**

```css
.MainFrame {
  max-width: 750px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}
div.Status {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid;
}
div.Disclaimer {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid;
}
div.Settings {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid;
```

```html
<div class="MainFrame">
  <div class="Status">
    <center>
      <h1>Home Screen</h1>
    </center>
    <center>Waiting for a command from the user.</center>
  </div>
  <div class="Disclaimer">
    <h3>This page will be used to direct user to other tools.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="Settings">
    <h2>Settings</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/Download/">
      <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download">
    </form>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, `<center>` was deprecated ages ago and removed from HTML5. And I, for one, will not get naked with you.

Comment: Like I said, new to html. This is my first project. It still works, so I'm not sure how it's been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that `padding` and `border` that belongs to box-model are counting to that `100%`.

for example: `width`100% + `padding` 10px will overflow. but using `box-sizing-border-box` will fix that, so use `box-sizing-border-box`

you can see more about `box-sizing` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

**Note:** `center` tag is deprecated don't use it, style in CSS instead.

**Note2:** I tweaked your CSS, reducing duplicated rules/properties.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.MainFrame {
  max-width: 750px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.MainFrame > div {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainFrame">
  <div class="Status">
    <h1>Home Screen</h1>
    Waiting for a command from the user.
  </div>
  <div class="Disclaimer">
    <h3>This page will be used to direct user to other tools.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="Settings">
    <h2>Settings</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/Download/">
      <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download">
    </form>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: `box-sizing` is the correct solution to the issue. This should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work. I must be missing something.

Comment: @bmradke just copy-paste, if you run my snippet you will see that is working fine :)

Comment: It ran fine when I edited the code, but when I run everything on a mobile browser I still have the width issues.

Comment: @bmradke you just can't :) this works everywhere. Just tested now. Working in mobile and in Desktop as expected

Comment: Give me time. I'll eventually get it!

Comment: the only thing here is that you need to add to your existent code is this: `*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`, so add this and test it.

Comment: I got it working, but there's still whitespace on left to get rid of. That's a different task. Thanks!

Comment: @bmradke see updated answer, I've updated my answer to fix that issue and improve your css a bit